# Sending messages from Server to Android App

Tags: java, android, mysql, server

I have an app that displays messages stored in a MySQL database. Right now, the user has to press a button to trigger a download of the messages to his or her phone. I want to implement the feature that if an update is made to a message the App automatically checks the database and downloads the new messages. All I need is a trigger to execute code if an update happened to the database.

I looked into Firebase but I have to create a new database to do real time changes. All I need is a trigger send from the Server, so that the App can execute code. I tried using AlarmManager to check for updates every once in a while, but it didn’t really work because the Alarm triggered just once when the App initialized the Alarm. Also, I read that this is not the right way to do it.

Is there a way to do it without third party programs? Can’t I use PHP to send a message to all Android Apps?

Thank you,

Manuel

Comment: you can use firebase cloud message (fcm) for communicate with server to device. but Firebase Realtime Database is recommended.  to know more about fcm:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 5):

You can use push notifications using FCM or GCM and handle the messages when they arrive, or you can create a websocket and connect your app to it. In my opinion the pushes are the best approach for you.

Comment: Just to reiterate, he should just use push notifications to signal the app to retrieve data from the server, For him to be able to react to those notifications he should leave the message and title field empty, but add a meta-data object. And please avoid web-sockets unless you absolutely need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using push notifications [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) that are going to be triggered by:
- your PHP backend when a new message is saved to the Database.
- a mysql store procedure triggered directly when a new element is stored.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a server-based database. It's not "connected" to your app in any way. To achieve this, you need to use a service that periodically checks the messages for you and sends a notification to the device. Google Cloud Messaging is widely used. I use FCM and its highly dependable. You can set it up without using the Firebase Database. Only use the Firebase Functions to periodically check if your data is updated then send a notification to the device

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase push messaging for your application : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/
The doc is straigthforward and has examples. If you don't want to send yourself the notifications for the server there are libraries (like pushraven for java)